# Bottom Navigation How to change fragment from inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation view with 3 fragments
I want to change from fragment 1 to fragment 2 from inside of fragment 1 and not from activity
Does anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: Are you using navigation component ?

Comment: No I am not using it

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a button in fragment 1. You click the button then it open fragment 2 with BottomNavigation item focus.

If you are using Navigation component then you just write

```
        val btnMove = rootView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnMove)
        btnMove.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.favoriteFragment) //here R.id.favoriteFragment is your fragment id where you want to navigate
        }
```

Comment: No this is not what I want this may change change the fragment to second fragment but it is not reflected on the bottom navigation bar